# Applescript do shell to create file with text and manipulate

Tags: shell, applescript

I am trying to write a simple logger with Applescript. I have a couple of questions

Firstly I am testing if a file exists, if it does not I want to create a file with that name and set the first line to a string "Counter:0".

So far I have this but my syntax is wrong. Appreciate any help as the info on the web is a bit slender.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set thePath to "/Data/GameLog/"
    set theFile to thePath & (do shell script "date '+%Y.%m.%d'" & ".log")

    if exists POSIX file thePath then
        --display dialog "Found"
    else
        do shell script "Counter:0" > echo thePath
    end if
end tell
```

secondly I would like to read the first line of the file (ie Counter:0) and increment the integer after the : by 1.

Help v.much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Based on vadian's answer:

```
set logFolder to (POSIX path of (path to home folder)) & "Desktop/" -- the trailing slash is crucial
set timeStamp to do shell script "date '+%Y.%m.%d'"
set logFile to logFolder & timeStamp & ".log"
if ((do shell script "test -d " & quoted form of logFolder & "&& echo true||echo false") as boolean) then
    try
        close access logFile
    end try
    try
        set fileReference to open for access logFile with write permission
    on error
        display alert "File already open"
        return -1
    end try
    set counter to (get eof of fileReference)
    if counter is not 0 then
        try
            set counter to (read fileReference from 9) as integer
        on error
            close access logFile
            display alert "Read error"
            return -1
        end try
        set counter to counter + 1
        set eof of fileReference to 0
    end if
    write ("Counter:" & counter) to fileReference as «class utf8»
    close access logFile
else
    display alert "Folder does not exist"
end if
```

The advantage is that this will not ignore errors. It will also be able to find your home directory without needing you to manually enter it in code. This is safe since we check for the logFolder first. The rest of the code can't fail if that folder exists. I am aware that AppleScript has a method for checking whether or not a file exists, but I have found that functionality to be fairly difficult to use when dealing with POSIX paths, so I'm using a do shell script instead, which naturally deals with POSIX paths.

Comment: what happens, if the log file is corrupted for some reason or it's still opened? Then AppleScript throws an error and you get potentially an leaking opened file descriptor. From my experience of more than 10 years AppleScript programming the try - error syntax is basically the most reliable one and you are free to catch further errors. By the way, there is a shorter `POSIX path of (path to desktop)` relative path, which has also the trailing slash for free

Comment: Right. You could put the actual `open for access` in a try block and if there's an error, close the file, then reopen. That would be a good solution, which I have used in the past. It takes a bit more effort to figure out a solution without dumping the entire code base into a try block, but it is definitely the correct and safer method. Your code should work correctly. If you're dumping large amounts of code into a try block, then you aren't trying hard enough. In the long run, such code will be tough to debug, as the code base evolves.

Comment: Also, please try to leave irrelevant things such as years of experience out of the discussion. Let your argument stand on its own merits. If you have to use external semi-relevant facts to bolster your argument, then perhaps your argument needs some work.

Comment: Okay, code has been updated to work better. This should account for your situations as well, and will not ignore any errors that should not be there. :)

Comment: Also, I was using `path to home folder` because that is typically the minimum directory level that is applicable to most scripts. Pretty much any file IO in a script (with a few exceptions) should either be sent to a subdirectory of the user's home directory, or to a temporary file in `path to temporary items`. The syntax is more flexible and easier to modify this way.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this, change the file path in the first line (consider the trailing slash)

```
set logFolder to "/Users/myUser/Desktop/" -- the trailing slash is crucial
set timeStamp to do shell script "date '+%Y.%m.%d'"
set logFile to logFolder & timeStamp & ".log"
try
    set fileReference to open for access logFile with write permission
    set counter to (get eof of fileReference)
    if counter is not 0 then
        set counter to read fileReference from 9
        set counter to counter + 1
        set eof of fileReference to 0
    end if
    write ("Counter:" & counter) to fileReference as «class utf8»
    close access fileReference
on error
    try
        close access logFile
    end try
end try
```

Comment: It isn't typically a good idea to wrap so much code in a try block. Simple errors might not be caught this way, leading to a bit of confusion.

Comment: there are no simple errors in this case. All possible errors are related to the read/write part. Please tell me a better syntax to close opened file descriptors reliably in any case

Comment: The point is, if you code it this way, then any small changes to the code base which results in an error will just fail silently. I'll post a better version in a sec.